# Force user to enter different digit

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-input

```
channel_total_list = []

get_channel_entry = int(raw_input('How many channels do you want to delete? '))

if get_channel_entry > 0:

    while True:

        user_channel_number = int(re.sub('\D', '', raw_input("Enter a channel number, (3d): "))[:3]);
        channel_total_list.append(user_channel_number)
        get_channel_entry = get_channel_entry - 1

        print channel_total_list
```

I am trying to get channel numbers from user input. If they enter same number for second time, I would like to ask user to enter different number.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are appending the user's input to `channel_total_list` you can check whether the input is already in the list with `if user_channel_number in channel_total_list` .

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a if statement in middle and you are good to go. 
Here is some modified code for you, "While" wasn't working in previous case as it was going to infinity.

```
channel_total_list = []
get_channel_entry = int(raw_input('How many channels do you want to delete? '))
leave = False
while not leave:
    user_channel_number = int(re.sub('\D', '', raw_input("Enter a channel number, (3d): "))[:3])
    if user_channel_number not in channel_total_list:
        channel_total_list.append(user_channel_number)
        get_channel_entry = get_channel_entry - 1
        if get_channel_entry == 0:
            leave = True
    print channel_total_list
```